# Converting array of characters to arraylist of characters

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am stuck at this problem (sending keys to GUI) where I am converting a string to a character array then I want the characterarray as an arraylist. Essentially:

```
String s = "ABC";
char[] cArray = s.toCharArray();
ArrayList<Character> cList = ??
```

I want `cList` to be a character arraylist of the form `['A', 'B', 'C']`. I don't know how to unpack it and then make an ArrayList out of it. `Arrays.asList() returns a List<char[]>` which is not what I want or need.

I do know I can loop and add to a list, I am looking for something simpler (surely one exists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, this does not exist in the core JDK, but the functionality is provided by several common libraries.

For example, Apache Commons Lang has a method with the following signature in ArrayUtils:

```
Character [] toObject(char [] input)
```

Similarly, the Google Guava library has a even more direct method in the Chars class:

```
public static List<Character> asList(char... backingArray)
```

Comment: While @Bhesh Gurung had a helpful answer I was looking for the more direct method, will accept this as my answer (and get to install Google Guava).

Answer (score 15):

You have to loop through the array:

```
List<Character> cList = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(char c : cArray) {
    cList.add(c);
}
```

Note: `Arrays.asList()` works only for reference types not primitives.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will autobox primitives.  Unless you're very concerned about performance I don't see a reason not to use it.

Comment: @Aurand, not really. `Arrays.asList(new char[]{'a','b', 'c'})` actually returns a `List` with only one element: an array with 'a', 'b' and 'c', not a `List` with three items as one would maybe expect.

Answer (score 3):

```
Character[] chArray = {'n','a','n','d','a','n','k','a','n','a','n'};

List<Character> arrList = Arrays.asList(chArray);
```